# Ionic 3 : native plugins not reloaded with livereload

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using Ionic 3 for a project with the [MSADAL native plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/ms-adal) and I need to attach a token to every requests using the MSADAL token cache and an Http interceptor.
But when livereload is done i've got an error in my Chrome console :

> 'Native: tried accessing the MSADAL plugin but it's not installed

It seems like all the native plugins are not included in the livereload.

So is there a way to include native plugins to be reloaded in a livereload action ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it on a device Android or IOS.
Also put your code inside platform.ready();

```
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {

        //here

    });
```

}

Comment: Yeah i've tried it, the problem is that it's working first time run but when it does a livereload on a save file event, the native plugins are not working anymore, so i found a solution using a promise fallback wich provides a mocked token but it's not really safe i think..